# How many turns of a 737 trim wheel equal 2.5 degrees stabilizer deflection?

Tags: flight-controls, boeing-737

After the well known crashes I looked at the question of stabilizer trimming. In case of trim runaway the pilot is supposed to "grasp and hold" the wheel manually steering the stabilizer. Hence my question: how many turns of the wheel to achieve a 2.5 degrees deflection of the stabilizer?

Comment: Good question. Neither FCOM, FCTM nor QRH answer how much one wheel rotation changes the trim, as far as I could find. The only reference to an amount of rotation is this: "Use force to cause the disconnect clutch to disengage. Approximately 1/2 turn of the stabilizer trim wheel may be needed." from the QRH, but this does not answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

### About 45 Rotations

In [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoNOVlxJmow) you can see Mentour pilot demonstrating manual trimming of a Boeing 737 NG. They start at about [11:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoNOVlxJmow&t=11m30s) with:

> we have 4 units nose down now

and at [12:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aoNOVlxJmow&t=12m30s) they say:

> now we are at about 3 degrees

I counted 18 full rotations of the trim wheel in this time. This would result in

$$ \frac{18}{4^\circ - 3^\circ} \times 2.5^\circ = 45 $$

rotations for 2.5 degrees of trim change.

*Note* that the trim indicator is not very precise, so the number is only an estimate:

[image: 737 Trim Wheel]
(frame from the video)

Comment: Thanks! I think that "units" are not exactly degrees, but the estimate is good. So when MCAS is active the wheel will turn 45 turns in 9 seconds!Terrific

Comment: @Ahmed I always wondered if those units are actually degrees. I [asked that question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70212/how-much-does-the-horizontal-stabilizer-on-a-737-move-for-one-unit-of-trim) now.

Comment: OK, it was unclear in the papers I read. Thanks