# How much does the horizontal stabilizer on a 737 move for one unit of trim?

Tags: boeing-737, trim, horizontal-stabilizer, units

Inspired by [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/70184/how-many-turns-of-a-737-trim-wheel-equal-2-5-degrees-stabilizer-deflection), what exactly is the meaning of a stab trim unit? Is it exactly one degree of stabilizer movement?

The 737 NG FCOMv2 (9.20.9 Flight Controls - System Description) only lists the ranges of the units:

> **Stabilizer Position Indication and Green Band**
>
> Stabilizer position is displayed in units on two STAB TRIM indicators located
>   inboard of each stabilizer trim wheel. The STAB TRIM indicators also display the
>   TAKEOFF green band indication.
>
> The trim authority for each mode of trim is limited to:
>
> - Main Electric Trim
>
>   - flaps extended 0.05 to 14.5 units
>   - [737-600] flaps retracted 4.10 to 14.5 units
>   - [737-700] flaps retracted 4.30 to 14.5 units
>   - [737-800] flaps retracted 3.95 to 14.5 units
>   - [737-900] flaps retracted 3.90 to 14.5 units
> - Autopilot Trim 0.05 to 14.5 units
> - Manual Trim -0.20 to 16.9 units.
>
> The green band range of the STAB TRIM indicator shows the takeoff trim range.
>   An intermittent horn sounds if takeoff is attempted with the stabilizer trim outside
>   the takeoff trim range.

The full range of travel can be seen as a black arc in the following image (taken from [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/58798/why-doesnt-a-full-yoke-deflection-also-change-the-stabilizer-trim-on-the-boeing/58803#58803)), which could be 17°, but it is hard to say from the image:

[image: 737 Horizontal Stabilizer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stab trim unit is an offset to the actual horizontal tailplane angle. It is added by Boeing to make the trim value positive.

1STU = 1 degree

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: [This post](https://www.pprune.org/tech-log/446606-747-400-other-boeing-aircraft-trim-question.html) on pprune.org confirms your statement. It also does not list any sources, but I'm going to accept for now...